# Hosting web-app which is compiled in Sun JDK 1.6

Tags: heroku

I am looking at Java/J2EE hosting options. I looked around and found AWS and more but Heroku seems to fit well for me. Especially because of the clarity and documentation.

But going through their docs, I came across the "Prerequisites" and it said that :

```
> Your application must run on the OpenJDK version 6, or 7 (8 is also available in beta).
```

Does it mean I cannot host my web-app which is compiled in Sun JDK 1.6?

Using : **Sun Java 1.6, JSF-2, Spring, Hibernate, MySQL**

I just want to know if my web-app with the above specifications can be hosted in Heroku.

Thanks,
Akshat

Answer (score 0):

OpenJDK 6 is compatible with Sun JDK 1.6 so you should be fine.  If that doesn't work for you can could bring your own JDK with you to Heroku.